# In Google bookmarks, how to rename a tag to two new tags?

Tags: google, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

In Google bookmarks, how to rename a tag to two new tags?  I.e. for each of the bookmark tagged 'foo', I'd like 'foo' deleted for it and two new tags 'new1' and 'new2' added.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in Google Bookmarks.
The quickest method would be the following:
At the bottom of the [Google Bookmarks page](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) you can click "manage labels" and than "rename" your existing tag. 
After you have done that, find your new tag on the very left. Click it to get a list of your bookmarks labeled with this tag and than manually add your second tag to every bookmark.

Comment: I have several hundred pages to manually add the second tag then. Phew! Is this use case really that hard to think of and support for Google?